# How to set up test suite using selenium webdriver eclipse and test NG

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I am new to selenium and so i want to seek advice for setting up my framework.

What i want to achieve is i want a test suite setup using selenium webdriver and eclipse in testNG format. I am looking for a test suite that runs through all the test listed in there (I will record and export script to java/test NG format using IDE and tweak as needed). So that on single click i can run through a series of tests for regression testing. And generate a report stating what passed and what failed

Any ideas how to do it or set it up or any small code required to invoke that whole test will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good tutorial on how to set up selenium webdriver and testNG framework.

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/download-and-install-java/

Hope it helps!